# Requests by multiple uris (asyncio)

Tags: python, asynchronous, websocket, request, python-asyncio

How to send multiple requests to the exchange websocket using `acyncio`?

[Exchange websockets documentation](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#websocket-market-streams)

*In fact, if you know how to send multiple requests through, for example, `requests` library using `asyncio` and not `websockets` library, that's great too*.

---

I want to send multiple requests to multiple websockets (two in the example) asynchronously using the `asyncio` library. Everything works for me with one request:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
from autobahn.asyncio.websocket import WebSocketClientProtocol
from typing import List


async def logging_message(_websocket: WebSocketClientProtocol) -> None:
    async for message in _websocket:
        data = json.loads(message)['data']
        print(data)

async def websockets_connect(_websocket_uris: List) -> None:
    async with websockets.connect(_websocket_uris[0]) as websocket:  ## !!! HERE I use bad thing: _websocket_uris[0]
        await logging_message(websocket)


websocket_uris = [
    'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=btcusdt@kline_1m/ethusdt@kline_1m/ethbtc@kline_1m/bnbbtc@kline_1m'
]  # The list is only of length 1, everything works

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(websockets_connect(websocket_uris))
```

**But** I can't use code like this with a single request, as the exchange has a limit on the length of one uri (`_websocket_uris[0]`), so I need to send multiple requests with different uris. Something like that:

```
async def websockets_connect(_websocket_uri: str) -> None:
    async with websockets.connect(_websocket_uri) as websocket:
        await logging_message(websocket)

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[
        websockets_connect(websocket_uri) for websocket_uri in websocket_uris
    ])


websocket_uris = [
    'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=btcusdt@kline_1m/ethusdt@kline_1m',
    'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=/ethbtc@kline_1m/bnbbtc@kline_1m'
]  # list of length 2, nothing works

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

**And** it doesnt work (bad request):

```
websockets.exceptions.InvalidStatusCode: server rejected WebSocket connection: HTTP 400
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very funny, heh:
I have a typo in the second uri

`'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=/ethbtc@kline_1m/bnbbtc@kline_1m'` to `'wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=ethbtc@kline_1m/bnbbtc@kline_1m'`